# Convertion of dual basis to standard basis, confused...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

a) Let $B=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ with $v_1=(2,1,-1),v_2=(2,-2,0),v_3=(1,1,1)$ be an ordered basis of $\Bbb R^3$. Determine the dual basis $B^*=(\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3)$in standard basis .

b) Determine the representation matrix of $\zeta_i:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ with $i\in \{1,2,3\}$ with respect to the standard basis

For a):

Let $\beta^*=\{f1,f2,f3\}$ be the dual basis of $B$. Converting this into a linear system of equations, we have:

$\begin{bmatrix}f_{11}&f_{21}&f_{31}\\f_{12}&f_{22}&f_{32}\\f_{13}&f_{23}&f_{33}\end{bmatrix}$*
$\begin{bmatrix}v_{11}&v_{21}&v_{31}\\v_{12}&v_{22}&v_{32}\\v_{13}&v_{23}&v_{33}\end{bmatrix}$ =
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

So we have $A*B=I$ and $A=B^{-1}$

$B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1/5&1/5&-2/5\\1/5&-3/10&1/10\\1/5&1/5&3/5\end{bmatrix}$

Now, this would be the dual basis with respect to B, is that correct? I still have to calculate the transformation matrix with respect to the standard basis. And to get the transformation matrix with respect to the standard basis, all I need to do in this case would be $$V_{[SB]}=T\{V_{[B]} \} \Rightarrow  1=T\{\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}\}_B\Rightarrow T={\frac{5}{3}}$$ So the first row of the transformation matrix with respect to standard basis would be $(\frac{5}{3},0,0)$. When it comes to change of basis I'm just very confused...Would be very grateful if someone could point out if there is something wrong with my logic here.

As for part b)

I take it that $\zeta_i$ would be the matrix $B^{-1}$  which i calculated for a).Then $\zeta_i=\{2+1+(-1)\}_{[SB]}={2}_{[SB]}=2$?. Is this correct?

Comment: The normal convention is that elements of $\Bbb R^n$ are column vectors, and those of $\Bbb R^{n*}$ are row vectors. But you appear to have them reversed. Does your book buck this very common convention, or did you flip them? In the standard column vector convention, $B$ corresponds to the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}2&2&1\\1&-2&1\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ whereas you appear to have used $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&-1\\2&-2&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair that...yeah i made a mistake.....i forgot....

Comment: @Paulsinclair thou are my next steps correct?

Comment: You are fine up to calculationg $B^{-1}$, but after that I cannot even tell what you are thinking. You use new notations without any explanation, in equations that have no sense that I can follow. The questions themselves are poorly worded, which makes it not entirely clear what they are after. Is this exactly the way the book states them, or did you "simplify" (i.e. botch) them? I can make guesses, which I've based my answer below on. There I go through the definitions to get to the answer, because I believe you are mistaking related calculations with the two bases, causing your confusion.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4310618/consider-the-following-systems-of-equations-with-unknowns-x-y-for-which-pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by making a distinction: $B$ is not a matrix. It is an ordered set of three linearly independent vectors. The matrix
$$\mathbf B = \begin{bmatrix}2&2&1\\1&-2&1\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
that you form from $B$ is a distinct object.

Any vector $x$ may be expressed in terms of the standard basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ of $\Bbb R^3$,where $$e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, e_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
by $$x = x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3$$
which gives us
$$x = x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + x_2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+ x_3\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Because $B$ is a basis, $x$ also can be written as a linear combination of its vectors:
$$x = x_1'v_1 + x_2'v_2 + x_3'v_3 = x_1'\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix} + x_2'\begin{bmatrix}2\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix}+ x_3'\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2x_1' + 2x_2' + x_3'\\x_1'-2x_2'+x_3'\\-x_1'+x_3'\end{bmatrix}$$
These two expressions for $x$ should be the same. So
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2x_1' + 2x_2' + x_3'\\x_1'-2x_2'+x_3'\\-x_1'+x_3'\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf B\begin{bmatrix}x_1'\\x_2'\\x_3'\end{bmatrix}$$

That is, $\mathbf B$ is the matrix that transforms the primed coordinates $(x_1', x_2', x_3')$ induced by the basis $B$ into the coordinates $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ induced by the standard basis. And therefore $\mathbf B^{-1}$ does the opposite, transforming $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ into $(x_1', x_2', x_3')$.

The dual space $\Bbb R^{3*}$ is the set of all *linear functions* from $\Bbb R^3$ into $\Bbb R$. Any such linear function $f$ can be written in the form
$$f(x) = f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}\right) = ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3$$ for some fixed $a,b,c \in \Bbb R$. Note that we can rewrite this with a row vector:
$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$$

This is why we can associate the dual space, which consists of linear functions from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R$, with the space of $3$ dimensional row vectors. They are actually two different spaces. Row vectors are not linear functions, and linear functions are not row vectors. But there is this natural identification of one with the other.

Since the expression $x = x_1'v_1 + x_2'v_2 + x_3'v_3$ is unique for each $x$, we can define three functions by $$\zeta_1 : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto x_1'\\\zeta_2 : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto x_2'\\\zeta_3 : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto x_3'$$
I'll skip the proofs, but these three functions are linear, and they form a basis for $\Bbb R^{3*}$. This is the definition of the dual basis to $B$: $B^* = (\zeta_1, \zeta_2, \zeta_3)$.

Now we can also use these to define a function $$\mathbf F : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3 : x \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}\zeta_1(x)\\\zeta_2(x)\\\zeta_3(x)\end{bmatrix}$$
Because the $\zeta_i$ are linear, this function is linear too. Further, since
$$v_1 = 1v_1 + 0v_2 + 0v_3\\v_2 = 0v_1 + 1v_2 + 0v_3\\v_3 = 0v_1 + 0v_2 + 1v_3$$
we have $$\mathbf F(v_1) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf F(v_2) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf F(v_3) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
from which it follows that $$\mathbf F(x) = \mathbf F\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1'\\x_2'\\x_3'\end{bmatrix}$$
Exactly the opposite of $\mathbf B$. Therefore $\mathbf F = \mathbf B^{-1}$.

But just as $B$ and $\mathbf B$ are distinct, though related, objects. So are $\mathbf B^{-1}$ and the dual basis $B^*$. But just as the columns of $\mathbf B$ are the column vectors of $B$, so the rows of $B^{-1}$ are the row vectors corresponding to $(\zeta_1, \zeta_2, \zeta_3)$. That is,
$$\zeta_1(x) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 15&\frac15&\frac{-2}5\end{bmatrix}x\\
\zeta_2(x) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 15&\frac{-3}{10}&\frac1{10}\end{bmatrix}x\\
\zeta_3(x) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 15&\frac15&\frac35\end{bmatrix}x$$

Though the way you have it worded is very unclear, I believe this is what question (a) wants. Question (b) is also stated in a confusing fashion. I can only guess it is asking for $\mathbf B^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the step-by-step explanation, it's very very helpful. Question b) is the exact same wording as in the question sheet thou, i also don't quite get it. The original language of the question sheet is not English, but i translated word by word, allthou in part b) it oculd be the "representation matrix" instead of "transformation matrix" but i dont think that makes it any clearer....And part b) i should have used the plural, as in matrices which would indicate that for each $i$, the representation matrix would be different.

Comment: @JerryHolmes - Okay, if it is a translation, then the confusion is much more understandable. Probably someone more savvy to the mathematics itself could have provided a clear translation, but it is asking too much for a novice to clearly translate mathematics they are just learning in one language into a different language without error, even if they are proficient in both languages.

Comment: Based on your comments. I now suspect (b) is asking for the three row vectors for $\zeta_i$ that I gave at the end, and (a) is asking for $$\zeta_1 = \frac 15 e_1^* + \frac 15 e_2^* - \frac 25 e_3^*$$ and similarly for $\zeta_2, \zeta_3$, where $e_1^*, e_2^*, e_3^*$ is the dual basis to the standard basis on $\Bbb R^3$. If $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$, then $$e_1^*(x) = x_1, e_2^*(x) = x_2, e_3^*(x) = x_3$$

Comment: i just edited the question,,,, i know now why both of us were confused...