# Consider the following systems of equations with unknowns x, y. For which pairs of values (a, b) does each system have an infinite no. of solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

For the below questions, I understand how to find the different values of $a$ when looking for a unique solution for each, but I do not understand the second part on pairs of $a$ and $b$ to find infinite solutions. I know on a line graph the same point of intersection may also appear in the case of the lines lieing on top of each other (infinite).
Other than being able to put these systems in matrix form, it seems unclear the fixed route to take rather than guessing. For example, one pair for System A would be (2,2), but I am unsure why this is the case and so I am unable to work out the others.

> "Consider each of the following systems of equations with unknowns $x$,
> $y$. For which values of a does each system have a unique solution?
> **For which pairs of values (a, b) does each system have an infinite number of solutions?**"

System A:
$$\begin{align*}
x - ay &= 1\\
ax - 4y &= b.
\end{align*}$$

System B:
$$\begin{align*}
     ax + 3y &= 2\\
     12x + ay&= b
\end{align*}$$

System C:
$$\begin{align*}
     x + ay &= 3\\
     2x + 5y &= b
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Please format your questions properly; I edited your previous one, you can see how to do it. [Here is a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Comment: I notice the equations weren't separated before. Each system simply has two linear equations.

Comment: I actually tried using the same formatting from my previous question, but it ended up merging the equations which made it unclear where the equation ends and it did not seem reasonable to have two different equations in a single line.

Comment: Sigh... Watch and learn. Last time. No "merging". Please review the tutorial.

Comment: It's the "\\" that prevents the equations appearing on the same line, right? The abscence of that is what I was describing as merging because it leaves both lines together.

Comment: Like I said: Please review [the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5024/742). It's explained there. I'm not your personal MathJax/LaTeX tutor.